# How do I lock the screen before hibernating?

Tags: hibernate

So when i hibernate my laptop the screen doesn't lock automatically.
To solve this i've changed `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` to contain:

```
su - myUsername -c "gnome-screensaver-command -l"
sudo pm-hibernate
exit 0
```

When running this file from a command line it works as intended (ie, lock the screen and then hibernate).
Unfortunately, when pressing the power button, it still just hibernates without locking the screen -what am I missing?

**EDIT**: I've added the line `whoami>>~/Desktop/test.txt` to verify which user is executing the `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`script. When pressing the power button, the file `test.txt` is created, but is empty. 
From this i conclude that the script is in fact being called when pressing the power button. What i do not understand is how the output of `whoami` can be empty...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `gnome-screensaver-command` needs to know the DISPLAY variable you are using. Since (in theory) multiple users can be logged in on one computer (also graphically), it needs to know whose display(s) to lock. The first one is ":0". Try

```
su - myUsername -c "DISPLAY=:0 gnome-screensaver-command -l"
```

Comment: I tried this code and got `Failed to get session bus: Could not connect: Connection refused`